# How to put a literal "?" in a Mysql query with bind variables

Tags: mysql, variables, bind

I have the following query:

```
select subclasses.id,participants_subclasses.participant_id
               from subclasses
              left outer join participants_subclasses on
                participants_subclasses.participant_id = ?
                and subclasses.id = participants_subclasses.subclass_id
           where
             subclasses.classification_id = ?
             and subclasses.showhover
           order by subclasses.seq,
      IF(LEFT(subclasses.code, 1) = '<',
   Extractvalue(subclasses.code, "//texts/text/content"),
 subclasses.code)
```

The above query is processing a table where the code column sometimes has text and sometimes has XML with text inside a tag. The above query works. The side-effect is that a code value cannot start with a "<" which should be acceptable, but the order by would mistake it for XML content. The query below would be more specific and accurate:

```
select subclasses.id,participants_subclasses.participant_id
           from subclasses
           left outer join participants_subclasses on
                participants_subclasses.participant_id = ?
                and subclasses.id = participants_subclasses.subclass_id
           where
             subclasses.classification_id = ?
             and subclasses.showhover
           order by subclasses.seq,
      IF(LEFT(subclasses.code, 5) = '<?xml',
   Extractvalue(subclasses.code, "//texts/text/content"),
 subclasses.code)
```

However this variation checking the XML header in the content fails with a "NameInput Array does not match ?" error in MySQL. It appears that the ? inside `<?xml` literal is being mistaken for a bind target. And I am passing 2 values to be bound - which again is correct.

So my question is - how do I get the `<?xml` literal to not be mistaken for a bind value target???

Comment: Have you tried escaping the question mark with backslash?

Comment: Yes I tried `<\?xml` and still got the above error.

Comment: Question marks inside quotes should not be interpreted as placeholders.  What language are you working in and how are you preparing the statement?

Comment: Good question @Jim Garrison. I am using PHP via ADODB interface via phpLens. And I looked up the error message in ADODB before posting, however the error message (to my surprise) is 2 errors run together. When I re-searched the ADODB source for "part" of the error message I discovered this is a bug in ADODB and have reported it to the authors. Thanks for making me revisit that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLVED**

This turns out to be a bug in ADODB interface from phpLens, and NOT in MySQL itself. It exists in current version which is 5.17 for PHP5.